# Return Value from TkInter Entry with Button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Python novice, here. I've noticed there are a lot of questions around the topic of returning values from a TkInter function, but none of the solutions seem to solve my issue.

I can successfully `print` `self.e1path` to the shell from within `getPath.submit`, but I cannot `return` it to the rest of my code. I'm using a print statement outside of the class to test whether I've successfully returned the CSV path.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
class getPath(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text="CSV Path").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self, width=50)
        self.e1Grid = self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.browse = tk.Button(self, text='Browse', command=self.getCSV).grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=self.submit).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def getCSV(self):
       self.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = (('Comma Separated Values', '*.csv'), ('All Files', '*.*')), title = "Choose a CSV File")
       self.e1.insert(10, self.fileName)

    def submit(self):
       self.e1Path = self.e1.get()
       return self.e1Path

app = getPath()
app.mainloop()
print(app)
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I needed to add a `self.destroy()` to the `submit` function. This stopped the mainloop and let me call on `self.e1path` outside of the function using `app.e1path`. New code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
class getPath(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text="CSV Path").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self, width=50)
        self.e1Grid = self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.browse = tk.Button(self, text='Browse', command=self.getCSV).grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=self.submit).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def getCSV(self):
       self.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = (('Comma Separated Values', '*.csv'), ('All Files', '*.*')), title = "Choose a CSV File")
       self.e1.insert(10, self.fileName)

    def submit(self):
       self.e1Path = self.e1.get()
       self.destroy()

app = getPath()
app.mainloop()
print(app.e1Path)
```